# Use Firebase API to handle PUT (PATCH) requests via x-editable inline editing

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, x-editable

I am currently using the following library to make inline edits to elements on my page (to cells in my table): https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/

As can be seen from [step 3 in their docs](https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html#date), when a user makes a change, I can update my database immediately.

I'm using Firebase for my database. The original data is sent to Firebase using the push() method -- thus each unique ID a random string of numbers/letters based on a timestamp.

**PROBLEM:** x-editable requires me to provide a URL to send my edits to but Firebase requires me to use their update() method to make changes to data in the database.  Thus, I need to figure out a way to send updates to Firebase using only a URL.

My code below:

```
// Each cell in my table has an ID; the code immediately below creates the unique ID for each date cell.

    var cell01id = snapshot.val().date + '-' + snapshot.val().initials + '-' + snapshot.val().age + '-date';
    // cell01id === 08/11/2015-BH-20-date

// after creating the ID, I then use innerHTML to display the data retrieved from firebase.  The syntax is taken from x-editable.
// notice [what goes here?] -- this is where I need to pass in a URL so x-editable can make edits.

    cell01.innerHTML = '<a href="#" id="' + cell01id + '" data-type="date" data-pk="1" data-url="' + [what goes here?] + '" data-title="Enter date">' + snapshot.val().date + '</a>';
    // cell01 === <a href="#08/11/2015-BH-20-date" data-type="date" data-pk="1" data-url="???????" data-title="Enter date">08/11/2015</a>
```

Comment: Can you isolate the problem into a minimal, complete example? If you're having trouble sending an update to Firebase, can you reproduce that problem without x-editable? If you're having trouble getting the update out of x-editable, can you reproduce that without Firebase? Doing so will make it a lot easier to help you. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks Frank. After further research, I've isolated the problem. In order to edit a Firebase value, I want to use the update() method. But in order to edit data using x-editable, I need a URL (see my code above for data-url=[what goes here?]).

Thus, I'm at a loss as to how I can combine these two.  In other words, when the user makes an edit, am I able to update firebase by simply accessing the URL?  If not, how can I send fb the updated info?

Comment: If I see X-editable's docs (https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html) correctly, then in step 7 they do a POST to a URL. That POST can overwrite the value at a location using Firebase's REST API (https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/api/). But without any security/authentication in place, that sounds like a recipe for abuse. You'll probably want to write some code to take control of sending the changes to the Firebase database. From the looks of it that requires you to hook into the "Work LOCALLY" flow of X-editable. You can then indeed call Firebase's `update()` method to update the db.

Comment: Aw gotcha!  Super helpful. thank you.  I'm very close to a solution... I can feel it.  When I include the .json at the end of the URL as per the instructions, I get a 400 status code with the following error:

{ "error" : "Invalid data; couldn't parse JSON object, array, or value. Perhaps you're using invalid characters in your key names." }

I think this is because the URL doesn't include the full JSON object: https://test-rt3.firebaseio.com/entries/-JwUiSc7IhXmJj7-_gp_/initials.json

But when I remove the '/initials'... error still exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After attending [HackReactor](http://heackreactor.com) and learning tons more about JS and RESTful APIs, I was able to figure out my problem.

Here is what I was missing.... for starters, I refactored my code so that the logic takes place in the makeEditable function.... I removed the logic from the href.

The url needs to match the data object I needed to update + append '.json' at the end of the URL.  Second, I have to make sure my type matches the field (example below is date). Third, contentType in my Ajax callback needs to be 'application/json' and dataType needs to be 'json'.

```
var makeEditable = function() {
  $('#' + cell01id).editable({
      url: 'https://fb-uniqueURL.firebaseio.com/entries/' + uniqueID + '.json',
      type: 'date',
      pk: uniqueID,
      title: 'Update Info:',
      ajaxOptions: {
        contentType: 'application/json',
        type: 'patch',
        dataType: 'json'
      },
      params: function(params) { 
        var obj = { "date": params.value };
        return JSON.stringify(obj)
      },
      success: function(response, newValue) {
        if (response.status == 'error') {
          return response.msg; //msg will be shown in editable form
        }
      }
  });
```